# Python: Finding the complete texts only after a specific word in a string using RegEx

Tags: python, regex

There is a text as follows:

```
text = list of documents check 01 original invoice in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment 
slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.com
checklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything 
written manually on the checklist will not be considered invoice parth enterprise â invoice no dated 
kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka 
mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order 
no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no 
vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of
```

**Objective:**
I want to extract the text after the word 'invoice', specifically second occuring of 'invoice'

**My Approach:**

```
txt = re.findall('invoice (.*)',text)
```

In the above approach, I was expecting a list of strings as follows:

```
txt = ['in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment 
    slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.com
    checklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything 
    written manually on the checklist will not be considered','parth enterprise â invoice no dated 
    kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment 
    taluka ..... #rest of the string]
```

But I am getting the whole string as given in `text` i.e. original string. 
If I use `text.partition('invoice')` I am not getting the correct strings as mentioned in `txt`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done by split() method
for example:

```
myText="jhon is going abroad jhon is thinking about future jhon is absent"
1)  print(myText.split('jhon',1)[1])
    output -> is going abroad jhon is thinking about future jhon is absent
2)  print(myText.split('jhon',2)[2])
    output -> is thinking about future jhon is absent
3)  print(myText.split('jhon',3)[3])
    output -> is absent

1 -> it will print text after first occurrence of jhon
2 -> it will print text after second occurrence of jhon
3 -> it will print text after third occurrence of jhon
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the 2 matches as in your question, you could use 2 capturing groups.

First match until the first occurrence of invoice. Then capture in group 1 right before the second occurrence of invoice.

Then match invoice again, and capture the rest of the string in group 2.

```
^.*? invoice (.*?) invoice (.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0pO5yS/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Io7qi7)

For example

```
import re

text = "list of documents check 01 original invoice in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.comchecklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything written manually on the checklist will not be considered invoice parth enterprise â invoice no dated kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of"
regex = r"^.*? invoice (.*?) invoice (.*)"

matches = re.search(regex, text)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
    print('\n')
    print(matches.group(2))
```

Output

```
in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.comchecklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything written manually on the checklist will not be considered


parth enterprise â invoice no dated kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't correctly understand OP's post and hence your output is not what OP expects. Check carefully OP's first string ends at `...will not be considered`. Also, there are no newlines in OP's post and they are just formatting issues which must have come due to cope paste while creating post. If you see OP has used just `.*` and whole of the text getting captured confirms there are no newlines in OP's text.

Comment: And in fact, your post's output is already what OP is getting from his regex which he mentioned in his post.

Comment: @Silvanas Sorry for the late response. I see what you mean, I overlooked the 2 outputs in the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `invoice (.*)` will match the first literal `invoice` followed by space and then `(.*)` will greedily capture the rest of the text in group1 which is what is happening and is the expected right behaviour.

But if you want to get the output like you mentioned, you will have to write your regex accordingly. You can use following regex to achieve the desired results,

```
invoice (.*?)(?=(?:(?:invoice.*){2,}|$))
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `invoice` - Matches literal invoice and a space
- `(.*?)` - Matches text in a lazy way
- `(?=(?:(?:invoice.*){2,}|$))` -  Look ahead to stop match either as soon as it sees 2 literal `invoice` texts or stops at the end of whole input

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WE81O0/1)**

Python demo,

```
import re

s = '''list of documents check 01 original invoice in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.comchecklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything written manually on the checklist will not be considered invoice parth enterprise â invoice no dated kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of'''
print(re.findall(r'invoice (.*?)(?=(?:(?:invoice.*){2,}|$))', s))
```

Output like you wanted,

```
['in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.comchecklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything written manually on the checklist will not be considered ', 'parth enterprise â invoice no dated kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:

The regex I used relies on a *positive lookbehind* and a *positive lookahead*:

```
(?<=\binvoice )(?:.*?)(?= invoice\b)
```

1. `(?<=\binvoice )` only match the following sub-expression if preceded by `invoice` starting on a word boundary.
2. `(?:.*?)(?= invoice\b)` match any character zero or more times (non-greedily) until the next characters are `invoice` ending on a word boundary.

Since I copied the input and included newline characters that were not in the original input, I had to use the flag `re.DOTALL` so that `.` can match the newline character. But this is not required if the input does not have newline characters (but it does no harm).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iddT6V/2/)

The code:

```
import re

text= r"""list of documents check 01 original invoice in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment
slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.com
checklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything
written manually on the checklist will not be considered invoice parth enterprise â invoice no dated
kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka
mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order
no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no
vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of"""

matches = re.findall(r'(?<=\binvoice )(?:.*?)(?= invoice\b)', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    print(f'\nMatch {i + 1}:\n', match, sep='')
```

Prints:

```
Match 1:
in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment
slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.com
checklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything
written manually on the checklist will not be considered

Match 2:
parth enterprise â
```

Comment: He only wants Match1 and Match2 and doesn't want Match3. Basically his Match2 is Match2+Match3 combined.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can probably be done more efficiently with a simpler regex used to split the input:

```
import re

text= r"""list of documents check 01 original invoice in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment
slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.com
checklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything
written manually on the checklist will not be considered invoice parth enterprise â invoice no dated
kashish aarcade baroi road 18 25 mar 2018 village baroi delivery note mode terms of payment taluka
mundra kutch supplierâ s ref other reference s gst no 24acypt3861 c1 z 7 dated buyer i buyer s order
no 21 jun 2017 abc corporation 5700214006 â dated 40 mwp solar power plant i despatch document no
vill bitta ta naliya abadasa despatched through destination march 18 terms of"""

#matches = re.split(r'\b\s*invoice\s*\b', text)[1:-1] # if arbitrary white space can come before and after "invoice"
matches = re.split(r'\b ?invoice ?\b', text)[1:-1]
for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    print(f'\nMatch {i + 1}:\n', match, sep='')
```

Prints:

```
Match 1:
in favour of company z 02 cjpc abstract sheet weighment
slip goods receipt note iz checklist creator id name 30009460 xyz@abc.com
checklist creation date 31 03 2018 checklist print date time 31 03 2018 10 45 57 note anything
written manually on the checklist will not be considered

Match 2:
parth enterprise â
```